# Using shell script for loops in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having trouble with the following shell command as part of a stage in my Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Run'){
  container('tool-build'){
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'slack', variable: 'WEBHOOK')]){

              echo "Sending Slack Notification"
              sh """
                 images=\$(docker images | grep "url.for.specific.repo.net" | awk 'NR>1 { print \$1":"\$2 }'')
                 for image in \$images;
                 do
                   label=\$(docker inspect --format='Maintainer:{{.Config.Labels.maintainer}}, From:{{.Config.Labels.from}}, Contains:{{.Config.Labels.contains}}' \$image);
                   PAYLOAD=\$(printf 'payload={"text": "New image available - %s - %s", "channel": "#some-channel", "username": "Some-Jenkins"}' "\$image" "\$label");
                   curl -v -X POST --data-urlencod "\$PAYLOAD" "$WEBHOOK";
                 done
              """
```

The output console from Jenkins seem to not be executing the commands inside `images=\$` and also ignores the for loop. How can I get the proper output from the bash commands and also not have the for loop ignored?

Jenkins output:

```
Sending Slack Notification

[Pipeline] sh

+ docker images

+ grep url.for.specific.repo.net

+ awk 'NR>1 { print $1":"$2 }'

+ images=
```

Comment: Could you extract the generated script and run in your shell? That may give more information.

Comment: Try `images=\$(docker images  --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}")` and then `echo \$images`

Comment: @MaratC Tried this. Getting wamer... It is now executing the docker commands inside as expected and printing the ouput correctly, however it is not saving the ouput to the variable `images`. Same thing happens with `label`. Output of echo is `<none>:<none>` but the correct image name gets printed by the docker images command.

Comment: Updated output of Jenkins: 
`Sending Slack Notification

[Pipeline] sh

+ docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}'

+ images='<none>:<none>

myrepo.net/amazon/amazonlinux2:20190129T000000Z'

+ echo '<none>:<none>' myrepo.net/amazon/amazonlinux2:20190129T000000Z

<none>:<none> myrepo.net/amazon/amazonlinux2:20190129T000000Z
+ docker inspect '--format=Maintainer:{{.Config.Labels.maintainer}}, From:{{.Config.Labels.from}}, Contains:{{.Config.Labels.contains}}' '<none>:<none>'
Error: No such object: <none>:<none>
+ label=`

Comment: @MaratC  This works except I don't want to loop through none:none, which is the default everytime docker creates an image. Hence why I had the specific grep originally :(  is there a way too exclude none values in --format?

Comment: Update: added -f "dangling=false" and it works! thank you